Upgrading System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to ver 8.0.1 causes Issues | JsonExtensions class not found
I recently upgraded my project from .NET 6 to .NET 8, and as a result also upgraded a couple of nuget packages to their latest stable version, one of them being System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt. I upgraded it from version 6.22.1 to 8.0.1.
When I ran a "Rebuild solution" in one of my classes JsonExtensions was being used as follows:
response = JsonExtensions.DeserializeFromJson<ResponseModel<TResponse>>(result);

Now after upgrading, I get an error

The name JsonExtensions does not exists in the current context

I tried searching for the breaking changes and when I did an incremental upgrade I noticed that it started breaking in 7.1.2.
Can someone guide me to a place where I can see the exact breaking changes or what exactly I need to do to fix this issue?

Quick search revealed JsonExtensions from legacy Azure SDK for .NET. Where the class comes from in your solution?

@GuruStron It comes from System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

The latest source code link, there is no JsonExtensions class.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/tree/dev/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

And it exist in v6.33.0, and is was missing from v7.4.0.

So the solution is we can use System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json to handle it. The useage like below.
// For System.Text.Json
var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseModel<TResponse>>(result);
var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(responseModel);

// For Newtonsoft.Json
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel<TResponse>>(result);
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseModel);

Of course we can also make custom extensions, depending on your needs. Here is the sample(using System.Text.Json) for you.
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
{
    public delegate string Serializer(object obj);
    public delegate object Deserializer(string obj, Type targetType);

    public static class JsonExtensions
    {
        
        private static Serializer _serializer = SerializeToJsonInternal;
        private static Deserializer _deserializer = DeserializeFromJsonInternal;

        public static Serializer Serializer
        {
            get => _serializer;
            set => _serializer = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        }

        public static Deserializer Deserializer
        {
            get => _deserializer;
            set => _deserializer = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        }

        public static string SerializeToJson(object value)
        {
            return Serializer(value);
        }

        public static T DeserializeFromJson<T>(string jsonString) where T : class
        {
            return Deserializer(jsonString, typeof(T)) as T;
        }

        public static JwtHeader DeserializeJwtHeader(string jsonString)
        {
            return Deserializer(jsonString, typeof(JwtHeader)) as JwtHeader;
        }

        public static JwtPayload DeserializeJwtPayload(string jsonString)
        {
            return Deserializer(jsonString, typeof(JwtPayload)) as JwtPayload;
        }

        
        private static string SerializeToJsonInternal(object obj)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
        }

        
        private static object DeserializeFromJsonInternal(string json, Type targetType)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, targetType);
        }
    }
}

